# loading class with __autoload

Tags: php, class, model, autoload

I'm trying to write my site in Controller-Model-View convention without using any framework but I have a problem with __autoload function.
Here's my **source_folder/model/database.class.php** file:

```
<?php
function __autoload($sName) {
    $aName = explode('_',$sName);
    if($aName[0] == 'Model')
        include '/model/' . strtolower($aName[1]) . '.class.php';
    else if($aName[0] == 'View')
        include '/view/' . strtolower($aName[1]) . 'class.php';
    else if($aName[0] == 'Controller')
        include '/controller' . strtolower($aName[1]) . 'class.php';
}
/**
 * Description of database
 *
 * @author Lysy
 */
class Model_Database {
   private $oConfig = new Model_Config();

   $this->oConfig->getConfigArray('database');

}

?>
```

And here's my **source_folder/model/config.class.php** file:

```
<?php
include_once '../config.php';

/**
 * Description of config
 *
 * @author Lysy
 */
class Model_Config {

    static function GetConfigArray($name) {
        return $config[$name];
    }
}

?>
```

The problem appears in line

```
private $oConfig = new Model_Config();
```

and it says **syntax error, unexpected T_NEW**. 
I don't understand where lies the problem, because I'm using *Netbeans IDE* and when I type in `private $oConfig = new M` the program gives me a hint with **Model_Config**.
I'd be very glad to read some advices and probable solution to this problem, regards :)

**EDIT:**
I rewrited the class **Model_Config** to look like this:

```
class Model_Database {

   private $oConfig;

   __construct() {
        $oConfig = new Model_Config();
    };

   $this->oConfig->getConfigArray('database');

}
```

But now there is a problem in line

```
__construct() {
```

*Netbeans* says that **__construct() is unexpected**, the error on the site stays the same, **unexpected T_NEW**

**EDIT2:** Oh sorry, too much C++, I keep forgeting about **function** word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign values to member variables using expressions. You have to do that in your constructor or inside of a method.

Comment: and while you're at it, you can't do that next line either (`this->oConfig->getConfigArray('database');`

Comment: I know about this line it was written just for test purposes. I edit the post to show that making constructor does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Model_Config contains more than that static method or why do you use "new Model_Config()" ?

That error message and "private" looks like you want to create an object direcly in your property. If you want to add an Model_Config object to the property of a specific class, you should use dependency injection. Here in your constructor for excample:

```
<?php

class YourClass
{

    private $oConfig;

    public function __construct(Model_Config $oConfig)
    {
         $this->oConfig = $oConfig;
    }
}
```

A nicer way of injection would be the usage of an interface as type hint. Maybe that method in your Model_Config shouldn't be static.

Comment: It was just for test purposes, I write lots of meaningless codes when I'm trying to test something to see various results and find what causes errors. Anyway I want static methods in Model_Config to access them without creating an object by simply Config::GetArray or sth like this and also non-static methods for wider use than just getting some variables from config.php file